# du --exclude-from cannot exclude

Tags: bash, du

I have a file (named excl.txt) **with null terminated** strings as follows:

```
/data/folder1
/data/folder2
/data/*.tsv
...
```

So as to calculate the size of the /data folder excluding the patterns in the above file, i use the command:

```
du -csh --exclude-from=excl.txt /data
```

But it doesnot work:

```
du -csh --exclude-from=excl.txt /data
552G    /data
552G    total

du -csh /data
552G    /data
552G    total
```

The excl.txt was initially created manually (by entering lines one by oney and pressing enter) and then the following command used so that the null term to replace the newlines

```
cat excl_init.txt | tr '\n' '\0' > excl.txt
```

What is going on?

Comment: Whats the output of `ls /data |grep -v tsv`

Comment: another way to see whats going on is to use the following command `du -csh --exclude-from=excl.txt /data/*`

Comment: `and then the following command used so that the null term to replace the newlines` Why? What for?

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on?

You passed a zero separated file, while `du` expects a newline separated file.

Replace zeros with newlines.

Alternatively, if you really have to, properly pass the expressions with `--exclude` option.

```
mapfile -d '' -t arr < excl.txt
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
     args+=(--exclude="$i")
done
du -csg "${args[@]}" /data
```

Answer (score 0):

seems now to work. Just added * at the end of all lines